# Creating cross-browser page with image positioned relatively over two rows of table

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-table

I'm trying to create a web page table layout which will look something like this:

[Link to the image http://kelostrada.pl/upload/test.png](http://kelostrada.pl/upload/test.png)

and I would appreciate your help.

I have created something like this right now and it works in Firefox, but whole table slides down in Chrome and Internet Explorer:

```
<div style="width: 1000px;">

    <img src="lupa.png" style="z-index: 10; border-width: 0px; width: 200px; top: 30px; right: 30px; position: relative; float: right;" />
    <table style="width: 100%; border-color: #6788bb; border-style: solid; border-width: 1pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #6788bb;">
                <td style="padding: 40px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: calibri; font-size: 18pt;">Wywiad Miesiąca
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: white;">
                <td style="padding: 20px;">
                    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; float: right"></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dictum urna justo, in mattis libero hendrerit sit amet. Nullam ac ultricies felis. Proin pulvinar nulla sapien, in molestie augue pharetra vel. Nam et elit quam. Donec non erat lobortis, ornare ligula a, blandit nisl. Vivamus ut pulvinar tortor, eget scelerisque sem. Quisque faucibus rutrum neque, at dapibus enim feugiat id.</p>
                    <p>
                        Morbi vel justo ultrices, fermentum lectus eget, condimentum arcu. Nullam commodo, neque eget fringilla fringilla, purus velit pretium nulla, vel bibendum augue enim ut lorem. Vivamus feugiat augue lorem, tempus pharetra sapien blandit id. Vivamus orci neque, laoreet vitae convallis id, malesuada et sem. Vestibulum tincidunt in mi eu ultrices. Praesent quis purus mattis, facilisis elit a, congue sapien. Nullam arcu nisi, sagittis eget nisi sed, posuere tempor odio. Aliquam vitae lorem nunc. Fusce ante libero, aliquam vel sollicitudin quis, pellentesque at mauris. Suspendisse quis arcu at odio gravida porttitor et at felis.
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how should I accomplish the result I want correctly?

If you want here is the webpage and you can test it how does it work in your browser: http://kelostrada.pl/upload/HtmlPage.html

Comment: Your example shouldn't be using a table. Is the real world application the same? If so, then you'll find it's much easier to get what you want by using div elements.

Comment: Would you be so kind to try and prepare such example with divs?
Real world application is using tables because I'm using sharepoint and it's pretty hard to design anything with divs there. But I can switch but didn't think it would make anything easier.

Comment: `table layout` - Don't do this, this is not what the `<table>` tag is for. Use the `<div>` element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the div with `1000px;` to have a `position:relative;` and the `img` tag inside it to have a `position:absolute;` instead of `position:relative;`

**For Instance,** this snippet code is from the link that you had provided. Just copy this and paste it in your HTML from `<body>` to `</body>` tag and it will work.

Here is the **[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rBXU9/1/)** for the same.

```
<body>
    <span class="test">TESTOWY NAPIS</span>
    <div style="width:1000px; position:relative;">
    <img src="lupa.png" style="z-index: 10; border-width: 0px; width:200px; top: 30px; right: 30px; position: absolute; float: right;"> <table style="width: 100%; border-color: #6788bb; border-style: solid; border-width: 1pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: #6788bb;">
            <td style="padding: 40px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: calibri; font-size: 18pt;">Wywiad Miesiąca
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: white;">
            <td style="padding: 20px;">
                <div style="width:200px;height:100px;float:right"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dictum urna justo, in mattis libero hendrerit sit amet. Nullam ac ultricies felis. Proin pulvinar nulla sapien, in molestie augue pharetra vel. Nam et elit quam. Donec non erat lobortis, ornare ligula a, blandit nisl. Vivamus ut pulvinar tortor, eget scelerisque sem. Quisque faucibus rutrum neque, at dapibus enim feugiat id.</p>
            <p>
                Morbi vel justo ultrices, fermentum lectus eget, condimentum arcu. Nullam commodo, neque eget fringilla fringilla, purus velit pretium nulla, vel bibendum augue enim ut lorem. Vivamus feugiat augue lorem, tempus pharetra sapien blandit id. Vivamus orci neque, laoreet vitae convallis id, malesuada et sem. Vestibulum tincidunt in mi eu ultrices. Praesent quis purus mattis, facilisis elit a, congue sapien. Nullam arcu nisi, sagittis eget nisi sed, posuere tempor odio. Aliquam vitae lorem nunc. Fusce ante libero, aliquam vel sollicitudin quis, pellentesque at mauris. Suspendisse quis arcu at odio gravida porttitor et at felis.
            </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> </table>
        </div>

    </body>
```

I have checked the same at my end and it works perfectly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow that works perfectly! I knew that it had to be absolute, but I didn't know how to make the position absolute against the table, not the whole page. Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer does not work in Chrome. It does however work in Firefox.

Comment: It does. Have you checked it??

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. I copied and pasted the code you provided and it does work.

Comment: Ah true, you need to correct your fiddle, probably you just copied my code and didn't save on editing

Answer (score 0):

I replaced every table element with divs. It looks fine to me.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhMUC/)

```
<div style="width: 1000px;">

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="z-index: 10; border-width: 0px; width: 200px; top: 30px; right: 30px; position: relative; float: right;" />
<div style="width: 100%; border-color: #6788bb; border-style: solid; border-width: 1pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <div style="background-color: #6788bb;">
            <div style="padding: 40px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: calibri; font-size: 18pt;">Wywiad Miesiąca
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">
            <div style="padding: 20px;">
                <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; float: right"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dictum urna justo, in mattis libero hendrerit sit amet. Nullam ac ultricies felis. Proin pulvinar nulla sapien, in molestie augue pharetra vel. Nam et elit quam. Donec non erat lobortis, ornare ligula a, blandit nisl. Vivamus ut pulvinar tortor, eget scelerisque sem. Quisque faucibus rutrum neque, at dapibus enim feugiat id.</p>
                <p>
                    Morbi vel justo ultrices, fermentum lectus eget, condimentum arcu. Nullam commodo, neque eget fringilla fringilla, purus velit pretium nulla, vel bibendum augue enim ut lorem. Vivamus feugiat augue lorem, tempus pharetra sapien blandit id. Vivamus orci neque, laoreet vitae convallis id, malesuada et sem. Vestibulum tincidunt in mi eu ultrices. Praesent quis purus mattis, facilisis elit a, congue sapien. Nullam arcu nisi, sagittis eget nisi sed, posuere tempor odio. Aliquam vitae lorem nunc. Fusce ante libero, aliquam vel sollicitudin quis, pellentesque at mauris. Suspendisse quis arcu at odio gravida porttitor et at felis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```